# How to get all allocated instances of specific class in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime, objective-c-runtime

I am trying to implement component for possibility to apply different skins to views and controllers at runtime without reinitialising these controls. I want to use such logic:

1. Declare protocol with methods for applying skins.
2. All necessary classes implements this protocol.
3. When user selects skin all instances of classes that conform to protocol receive message to apply skin.

So I know how to get all necessary classes that conform to my specific protocol by using `objc_getClassList` and `class_conformsToProtocol` functions.
But how to get all allocated instances of these classes for sending message to them?

I know that it could be implemented by internal logic of every class by storing all instances in static storage and returning array by class method. But it isn't elegant solution. I'm finding more universal solution where I can add new skinnable controls in easy way.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using `NSNotificationCenter`?

Comment: @nhgrif Using of `NSNotificationCenter` is possible but in this case I need add `self` as observer in every class. Also compiler won't generate any warning for me or other developer if me/he doesn't do it while implementing new class that implements protocol for applying skins.

Comment: Adding `self` as an observer in every class is easy.  You should be developing a base class that all the other classes inherit from, and this base class can register (and unregister in dealloc) for the notification and have the method set up that it responds to.

Comment: @nhgrif The main issue that inheritance can't be applied here because classes that could apply skin may be subclasses of different classes: UIView, UILabel, UIButton, UIViewController and etc. So there are no base class.

Comment: First of all, `UIViewController` shouldn't be one of the classes.  Second of all, you can make a handful of base classes.  There aren't THAT many subclasses of `UIView` (which should be the only ones you worry about).  And each of these base classes is only a handful of code.  One line to register for notifications in init, one line to unregister in dealloc, and a stub method that responds to the notification.  You can put every one of these base classes in a single `.h/.m` even.

Comment: @nhgrif I don't think that inheritance is the best solution here. Except of using standard cocoa touch controls I need consider of using third-party controls where I also have to implement logic for `NSNotificationCenter`. About `UIViewController` you are absolutely right, skinnable should be it's view but not controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds very much like you're reinventing [`<UIAppearance>`](http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/). You should at least start there. It's what it's for. Also see [Peter Steinberger's](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/uiappearance-for-custom-views/) writeup for discussion of adding custom properties.

To your basic question, there is not a runtime call to enumerate all allocated objects of a class. It would add a lot of overhead to provide that (objects come and go all the time and very quickly). Even if you could do it, you probably shouldn't. But since you're talking about visible views, then you can always do this by enumerating the view hierarchy under `NSWindow`. Any views not currently in the view hierarchy should be expected to correctly redraw in an new style the next time they come on the screen.

But I'd start with `<UIAppearance>`.

Comment: Rob, thank you for idea, I think UIWindow hierarchy + <UIAppearance> is good kick to start.